# Unremovable objects/lines QGIS 3.x

Tags: polygon, qgis-3, error, digitizing

How can I remove "red lines" that become permanent to my map canvas while trying to digitize different shapes. The program just leaves the outline of what I'm trying to draw. It still remains even if I close all of the layers and empty everything. I've encountered this error numerous of times when creating circles, lines etc.

Comment: What are those "red lines"? Can you add a screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

I've tried something but the shortest way I found is using *Python Console*.

I realized when I draw something, QGIS adds that drawing as a `QGraphicsItem` object to map canvas scene in first order. Try this:

- Open *Python Console* in QGIS
- Copy-Paste the line below

  ```
    iface.mapCanvas().scene().removeItem(iface.mapCanvas().scene().items()[0])
  ```
- If map canvas has multiple items like you mentioned, run the code line again. If it hasn't, don't run again, otherwise you may encounter unexpected results.

**Edit**: The code line above was working until a certain QGIS 3.x version. After updates to the source code it is causing QGIS to crash.

Comment: I tried that line you suggested but when I run it QGIS just crashes.. I figures how to make the " red line" appear. You start drawing a line and before finishing it you click  for example "add ring" icon.

Comment: Adding a screenshot and specifying which tool you use when getting that error may be helpful for users to answer the question correctly.